# How to programmatically maximize a window using LaunchUriAsync in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

How do I maximize/minimize launching/current windows store applications programmatically using LaunchUriAsync in Windows 8?

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
        options.TreatAsUntrusted = false;
        options.DisplayApplicationPicker = false;
        Uri target = new Uri("ms-mail:");
        bool isSucceed = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(target, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this in Windows 8, but Windows 8.1 added the [DesiredRemainingView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.launcheroptions.desiredremainingview.aspx) property to LauncherOptions, wherein you indicate how you want the launching app to remain on the screen (UseLess, UseHalf, UseMore, UseMinimum, and UseNone).