# Launching a URI from Windows 8.1 app in full screen mode

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm trying to launch an app in full screen mode from URI from my Windows 8.1 app. But it keeps launching the app in half screen mode. I don't want to open other apps in half screen! Instead I want to launch an app in full screen.

I want other apps to take place of my app window. Actually, I am navigating from one app to my another app. Here is my code for launching another app:

```
var appUri = new Uri("sm-calib://test");
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(appUri);
```

Here `sm-calib` is my other app protocol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically maximize a window using LaunchUriAsync in Windows 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950284/how-to-programmatically-maximize-a-window-using-launchuriasync-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately impossible. We do not control this parameter.